# ¿Cómo hago para tomar las columnas de un workbook por su nombre y no por header?

Tags: base-de-datos, excel, vba

Buenos días colegas!

Paso a decribir el escenario y luego el problema:

[image: Salto en headers, A2-B2, C3-D3-E3]

Yo usaría los nombres de los headers pero me traen problemas a la hora de llamarlos porque el cliente me manda en ese formato el excel y no son flexibles a cambiar el formato. Entonces recurrí a intentar leerlo por la letra de las columnas y en este caso a partir de A5 hasta donde termina el rango.

Quiero leer el workbook como si fuera una base de datos para ello uso el siguiente ConnectionString:

**`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Autom\Amdocs9_1\EPC\Fase V - Billing Offer\Excel\Unificado.xlsx; Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;";`**

Y dentro hago el select correspondiente:

**`select * from [Configuration$A5:ATX5273]`**

Hasta ahí todo bien, mi problema es que no puedo meter las columnas en el select... por ejemplo columna B, columna F, columna Z.

He estado googleando 3 dias y no encuentro respuesta espero puedan ayudarme.

El lenguaje con el que trabajo es VBSCRIPT (QTP).

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví, no tenia que hacer nada raro, las columnas en lugar de aparecer como A, B, C, D. Aparecen como F1, F2, F3, F4, F5

Por lo tanto si quiero filtrar columnas sería por medio de la siguiente consulta:

**`select F1, F5 from [BillingOffer$B5:CI2155]`**

Comment: Jose. Solicita una fusión de cuentas ya que tener dos cuentas va contra las políticas de [se] además de que se vuelven complicadas operaciones como aceptar tu propia respuesta. Para ello sigue el enlace al pie de página "Contactános".